# Check if string is a grammatically valid sentence?

Tags: java, nlp

Is there a way to check if a string represents an English sentence? I am currently looking at java packages but I cannot find anything that does it yet.

i.e.

```
the weather is good (valid)
the good is weather (invalid)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: And how do you define a sentence?

Comment: check if it starts with a capital, ends with a period and contains spaces.

Comment: What do you need the sentence for? are you using it as a variable or something? or just to print? are you using a form or some kind of applet?

Comment: @pst am I supposed to understand that?

Comment: I mean if it is a valid sentence: i.e.
the weather is good (valid)
the good is weather (invalid)

Comment: You mean to check sentence structure?

Comment: Yeah i want to check the structure. Something with POS tagging

Comment: POS Tagging.

you know that a similar questions was asked here.They have a list of java library's to use.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293636/what-is-a-good-java-library-for-parts-of-speech-tagging


you can look there for assistance.

Comment: I have done the POS Tagging. I need to know if what i get is valid as a sentence

Comment: What POS Tagger did you use? the answer depends on what you use

Comment: Stanford NLP. But it doesn't check validity

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is NLP parser (grammatical analysis).

[This one](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) is written in Java and it is fantastic.

Comment: I have that but i am not sure if it recognizes whether the sentence is valid. It does the tagging

Answer (score 0):

While I realize the OP referenced Java, I will offer that the MS Office suite has a limited grammar checking engine that is intended to perform very top-level corrections/suggestions for what I would imagine is a fairly simplified set of sentence patterns it recognizes, eg, those found in typical office correspondence. I don't think it pretends to be exhaustive or anything like a full English analysis tool, but it might serve the basic purpose in a limited form.

The check is exposed through COM via the CheckGrammar method, which is called from the Application object of the host Office application. You supply the text to be checked. It can identify several problems in addition to fragments, such as tense and number disagreements, so you might have to refine the results it offers. It's far from perfect, but does give it the old college try :)