# Part-of-speech tagger mapping in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp

I am currently using Apache Solr to build a search engine. The queries in Solr are of the field:value format. Now I want to use a part-of-speech tagger to separate the subject, verb and predicate and search the values in each fields. For example, if I input "Who likes Starbucks" then I need some code to give me "q=subject:*&verb=likes&object=starbucks". Is there any library that can handle this job? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a number of POS taggers.  Here is another StackOverflow posting about this: [What is a good Java library for Parts-Of-Speech tagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293636/what-is-a-good-java-library-for-parts-of-speech-tagging)

Answer (score 0):

I think several people have used [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/sandbox.html) for this, see [solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA)

Comment: "UIMA Module was removed in Solr 7.5"