# how to detect who, what, when, where from a sentence as user types

Tags: regex, algorithm, nlp, tokenize

Is there a good algorithm/tokenizer/regex or some other technique that can detect which part of an English language sentence is the "who", "what", "when" and "where" as the user is typing?

Ideally it would be something that could be implemented in either elastic search or javascript or .net.

Alternatively maybe something that can just detect the subject and verb of a sentence.

If it works for English, would it be something that can be internationalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific technique for all of these four questions, but there is advanced research carried out related to each.

"Who", "What" and "Where" could be resolved by Named entity recognition.(http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml).

"When" is probably more related to the area of Temporal tagging.(http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml).

The problem of detecting subjects, verbs or any other part of speech is called part-of-speech tagging, for which there exist numerous libraries.

[What is a good Java library for Parts-Of-Speech tagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293636/what-is-a-good-java-library-for-parts-of-speech-tagging)

Comment: POS tagging does not label syntactic functions (e.g. subject, objects), one would need a parser to perform syntactic analysis.

Comment: I think the key bit in the question not addressed in this answer is "as the user is typing." Most tools of this nature assume input to be complete sentences.